# Apache Ignite - what is best way to store and search objects with field of type Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: ignite

i need to store object with following list of attributes:

```
public class Entity {
    String guid; //pk
    long timestamp;
    String domain;
    String type;
    Map<String, List<String>> tags;
}
```

i need search by all those fields and idea was to use sql query with indexes. According to documentation this is only possible with table/cache created via SQL DDL. But SQL DDL doesn't seem to support collections.
What is best way to use collection as value object property and have fast/index search?

Answer (score 2):

It's not true that you need to use SQL DDL, you can use [annotations or query entities](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/sql-api) to *define* the SQL schema.

But you're right, there is no way to directly query collections.
Instead, you need to normalise your tables. In this case, you may need a couple more tables EntityTags and EntityTagsList or something. Make sure you [define affinity keys](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-modeling/affinity-collocation#configuring-affinity-key) to make your joins efficient.